# How to fix Batch not loading website link correctly?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wanted to make a batch program to start all of my web browsers and open them to a websites saved on my computers local storage. Everything works correctly until the URL is copied into cmd and it changes the link.

```
start "" "Google Chrome" "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Programming/Web%20Dev/Websites/PRP%20Website/index.html"
```

When I run this code the two places there is %20, only a 0 gets put into the cmd so the new code looks like  this

```
 start "" "Google Chrome" "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Programming/Web0Dev/Websites/PRP0Website/index.html"
```

I do know I could change the folder name and the problem would be fixed, but I was hoping there would be a way to fix this problem with code and not the file names

Comment: Please try to substitute a single space for the `%20` occurrences: `"file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Programming/Web Dev/Websites/PRP Website/index.html"`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you for the help

Comment: My pleasure. The %20 is just a hexadecimal representation of a space in URLs (i.e.decimal 32), but your environment seems to interpret the %2 as something else, leaving the 0.  If you got a minute you might also try the original, with the %20's, but wrapped in *single* quotes. I'm curious if that works.

Comment: Using single quotes does not work. If it helps I’m  running windows 10 and just using the cmd prompt that comes with the system.

Comment: The simplest way is to use **`%%`** instead of **`%`**.

Comment: An URL must be [percent encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encoded-bytes). The web browsers do that if an URL is not already percent encoded. Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing a batch file interprets a percent sign as begin/end of a batch file argument reference or a loop variable reference or an environment variable reference. It is necessary to escape `%` with one more `%` to get it interpreted as literal character. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `call /?`, `for /?` and `set /?` and read the output helps explaining the usage of `%`.

Comment: @IanHalstead, single quotes are just regular characters, they have no special meaning in cmd.exe, so it wouldn't be advisable to use them for quoting a URL anyway!

Comment: @Compo Update: You can use %%20, and the code will work if you just use a space. Thank you for the clarification, I just starting using batch yesterday so I'm very new.

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is that cmd.exe is interpreting "%2" as the second parameter on the command line. Since there is no second parameter on the command line "%2" is replaced with nothing. This can be overcome by:

1) Replace "%20" with a SPACE " " character

2) Escape the "%" with another "%" character, resulting in "%%20".

Comment: What do you mean by "interpolation"? `cmd` only uses `"` for quotation, `'` is just a regular character...